# Specify per-file-ignores with pyproject.toml and flake8

Tags: python, configuration, lint, flake8

I am using flake8 (with flakehell but that should not interfere) and keep its configuration in a `pyproject.toml` file. I want to add a `per-file-ignores` config but nothing works and there is no documentation on how it is supposed to be formatted in a toml file.

[Flake8 docs](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/options.html#cmdoption-flake8-per-file-ignores) show only the 'native' config file format:

```
per-file-ignores =
    project/__init__.py:F401
    setup.py:E121
    other_project/*:W9
```

There is no description / example for pyproject.toml.

I tried:

```
per-file-ignores=["file1.py:W0621", "file2.py:W0621"]
```

and

```
per-file-ignores={"file1.py" = "W0621", "file2.py" = "W0621"}
```

both of which silently fail and have no effect (the warning is still raised).

**What is the proper syntax for per-file-ignores setting in flake8/flakehell while using pyproject.toml?**

Answer (score 44, accepted):

flake8 does not have support for pyproject.toml, only `.flake8`, `setup.cfg`, and `tox.ini`

---

disclaimer: I am the flake8 maintainer

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I have realized that the pyproject.toml support was actually from flakehell ... And in my case I should use flakehell Exceptions syntax.
https://flakehell.readthedocs.io/config.html
Flakehell itself does not support this particular setting.

Comment: @PiotrZakrzewski , how did it go with the "exceptions syntax"? I'm trying to have something like:

```
[tool.flakehell.exceptions."**/test/*.py"]
pydocstyle = ["-*"]
```

but it does not exclude that specific plugin for the passed glob pattern :/ ...

Comment: does this answer need to be updated if @siruku6 is correct?

Comment: @Zaffer nope, pyproject-flake8 is not official nor supported, nor does it even work correctly (and will break every release as it uses private internal implementation details)

Comment: please implement PEP518, it is standard now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: A standard lib will be available in Python 3.11 (tomllib)

Comment: @marscher PEP 518 is a standard **for packaging tools** it is not a standard for "shove your configuration here"

Comment: excuse my ignorance, but why doesn't flake8 support pyproject.toml? How can there be 3+ forks of the project to resolve this issue? Is this a power-game or is it logical?

Answer (score 26):

Currently, [pyproject-flake8](https://github.com/csachs/pyproject-flake8) enables you to write your flake8 settings on `pyproject.toml` like this.

```
# pyproject.toml
[tool.flake8]
    exclude = ".venv"
    max-complexity = 10
    max-line-length = 100
    extend-ignore = """
        W503,
        E203,
        E701,
    """
    per-file-ignores = """
        __init__.py: F401
        ./src/*: E402
    """
```

Comment: Some alternatives: [flake9](https://gitlab.com/retnikt/flake9) and [flake518](https://github.com/carstencodes/flake518)

Comment: There is also [ruff](https://github.com/charliermarsh/ruff), which is a different linter altogether, but a bit more powerful with ability to autofix a lot of stuff and `pyproject.toml` support built-in

Comment: @LordBertson How can I express my love because you provided a next-level linter? Unfortunately, I cannot upvote your comment 3 times...

Comment: Unfortunately `pyproject-flake8` doesn't work with Python 3.12, while [`Flake8-pyproject`](https://github.com/john-hen/Flake8-pyproject) does.